# Sorting data in memtable (memstore) of Cassandra (Hbase)

Tags: cassandra, hbase

I know that incoming data to the system is first put in memory (memtable or memstore). In the buffer, data is sorted according to row key and column name. When the buffer size reaches a certain limit the data is flushed to disk. If the buffer size limit is configured to a large value (~256 MB) the number of data points must be very large (~ tens million). What are data structures and sorting algorithms used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element of storing data in HBase is [KeyValue](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/KeyValue.html). It consists of pointer to bytes array there actual values are stored, add contains the length and offset. So KeyValues are tightly packed into some bytes arrays. To index them KeyValueSkipListSet (old version) or CellSkipListSet (new version) are used. Both class are build on top of [ConcurrentSkipListMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) java implementation of [Skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

Answer (score 0):

Internal storage data structure for HBase Store files/HFiles are LSM (Log-Structured Merge) trees. LSM trees are similar to B+ trees but it allows better scalability and distributed usage because it has an on-disk log file and in-memory store. So, once memstore reaches its limit, it gets flushed to the disk similar to the B+ tree data structure. Later on, its gets merged with other Store files to form a big Store file.

Benefits of this data strcuture over B+ tree is that disk io is not required for every update/delete which results in significant improvement.

Comment: You misunderstood my question, I guess. I am asking about sorting in memory before flushing data to disk.